# How do I add to a unified patch file?

Tags: diff, patch

If I have a patch file in the unified patch format like the example below, how do I add lines to it so that those lines are then added by the (applied) patch?

```
--- lao 2002-02-21 23:30:39.942229878 -0800
+++ tzu 2002-02-21 23:30:50.442260588 -0800
@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
-The Way that can be told of is not the eternal Way;
-The name that can be named is not the eternal name.
The Nameless is the origin of Heaven and Earth;
-The Named is the mother of all things.
+The named is the mother of all things.
+
Therefore let there always be non-being,
so we may see their subtlety,
And let there always be being,
@@ -9,3 +8,6 @@
The two are the same,
But after they are produced,
they have different names.
+They both may be called deep and profound.
+Deeper and more profound,
+The door of all subtleties!
```

Comment: What do you mean by “add lines”? What do you want to add? Do you want to change the patch into a patch that makes a different modification? How do you expect to describe the modifications?

Comment: I think I want to add a few more additions to a hunk.

Comment: Do you want to edit the file manually? Or are you looking for a tool to modify the patch with instructions like “add three more lines after line 4”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short: you don't do this.

Long: Here's why

- A unified-diff is a *script*, using *line-numbers* and *counts* which tie-in to the content of the diff.
- It's possible to manually make simple changes to this script (I do...), but
- A unified-diff is mainly useful with the `patch` program, and
- `patch` checks for consistency between the parts of a diff, and
- `patch` will reject the parts which it finds are inconsistent.

These lines contain line-numbers and counts:

```
@@ -1,7 +1,6 @@
@@ -9,3 +8,6 @@
```

and the counts must match the number of leading `+` or `-` marks in the remaining lines of the diff.

So you don't do this manually.  Someone *could* write a program to do this.  However, it's not in [`patchutils`](http://cyberelk.net/tim/patchutils/) (someone's idea of useful applications for manipulating patch-files), though you might find its `rediff` and `combinediff` scripts helpful in hand-editing patch-files.

There are few applications which deal with patch-files in any case (perhaps *someone* has written one).

The usual practice here is to regenerate the diff by

1. get the original sources (before the patch)
2. make a patched version of the sources (applying the patch)
3. make your additional changes
4. construct a new patch (across both sets of changes), or incremental patch (for just your changes).

That's simple to do with `diff` and `patch`.  Because it's simple, not many people will write tools to do this.

Further reading:

- [diff - compare two files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html)
- [patch - apply changes to files](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/patch.html)
- [diffstat - make histogram from diff-output](http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/diffstat.html)
- [patchutils - a small collection of programs that operate on patch files](http://cyberelk.net/tim/patchutils/)